Анимация css и js не работает корректно, незнаю что делать
Хотелось сделать примерно как здесь
html
   <div class="container">
    <div class="text-block active">Здраствуй, Мой дорогой друг..</div>
    <div class="text-block">Позволь мне кратко рассказать про этого ГеймМастера</div>
    <div class="text-block">Хотелось бы сказать об его главном достоинстве..</div>
    <div class="text-block">Знаете ли вы про чеховское ружьё?</div>
    <div class="text-block"> это когда каждый, даже крошечный элемент истории должен иметь значение. Чеховское ружьё может непосредственно влиять на ход событий или быть явным или косвенным намёком на дальнейшее развитие.</div>
    <div class="text-block">Блёба - мастер в этом, каждое его повестование будет наполнено загадками которые сломают вам мозги и не только</div>
    <div class="text-block">Поэтому я предлагаю вам узнать узнать каких героев он ведёт и способен ли он взять вашего адепта</div>
    <div class="text-block">Удачи вам выжить..</div>
  </div>

css
.text-block {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity var(--animation-duration);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.text-block.active {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fade-in-out var(--animation-duration) ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes fade-in-out {
    0%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    50% { opacity: 1; }
}

Js
// Get the text blocks
const textBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.text-block')

// Set animation duration and timing function as CSS variables
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--animation-duration', '5s')
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
    '--animation-timing-function',
    'ease-in-out'
)

// Function to show the next text block
function showNextTextBlock() {
    // Find the active text block
    const activeTextBlock = document.querySelector('.text-block.active')

    // Remove the 'active' class from the active text block
    activeTextBlock.classList.remove('active')

    // Find the next text block
    const nextTextBlock = activeTextBlock.nextElementSibling || textBlocks[0]

    // Add the 'active' class to the next text block
    nextTextBlock.classList.add('active')
}

// Call the function to show the next text block
showNextTextBlock()

// You can add a timer or event listener to call the function periodically
setInterval(showNextTextBlock, 10000) // Change the interval as needed



добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Я бы сделал как-то так.
В css добавляем еще один класс
.hide {
    display: none;
}

На jQuery пишем функцию показа блоков (на pureJS перепишите сами)
function showNextBlockRecursively() {
  //у текущего `.active` блока удаляем класс `.active` и добавляем класс `.hide`
  //что даст нам его скрытие после отрабатывания анимации
  $('.text-block.active').removeClass('active').addClass('hide');
  //если у нас еще остались не показанные блоки
  if ( $('.text-block:not(.hide)').length > 0 ) {
    //первому из них добавляем класс `.active`
    $('.text-block:not(.hide):first').addClass('active');
    //так как время анимации у вас `5s` - создаем таймер на это время
    //по его истечении снова вызываем эту же функцию
    setTimeout(function(){
      showNextBlockRecursively();
    }, 5000);
  } 
}


Ну и на событие полной загрузки страницы вешаем вызов этого же таймера
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        showNextBlockRecursively();
    }, 5000);
});

